# Model.create is not a function - strapi

Tags: javascript, database, sql-insert, bookshelf.js, strapi

I have a few unique fields when creating model in strapi's admin ui.

I realized that when field is not provided during the api call, it'll give an error message of `500` instead of the proper error message.

I do understand why there's an error since I can see the log in backend console and I have scanned through posts such as https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1189 and https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1175

After reading those issues, I believe the best way is to go `/api/controllers` and create a function such as `create` to override the one provided but I get an error of `Model.create is not a function`

I have not do much in the controller yet so code is slim.

```
module.exports = {
    /* Strapi has default create function
     * But because of the error message it provide is vague, will have to customize the controller */
    create: async (ctx) => {
        try {
            console.log(ctx.request.body, 'ctx');
            const article = await Article.create(ctx.request.body);
            console.log(article, 'article');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e, 'error');
        }
    }
};
```

I have read the issue ticket `https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1505`
But I am using 
strapi: 3.0.0-beta.17.5
node: v10.17.0
npm: 6.11.3
db: sqlite3 (local) postgresql (staging)

Anyone know what I might have done wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help and advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the default controller functions here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#extending-a-model-controller

You will see how to use service functions to create entries.

I don't suggest you to use Model Global variables.

```
const { parseMultipartData, sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Create a record.
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */

  async create(ctx) {
    let entity;
    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      entity = await strapi.services.restaurant.create(data, { files });
    } else {
      entity = await strapi.services.restaurant.create(ctx.request.body);
    }
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.restaurant });
  },
};
```

Comment: I did read that too but guess I had typo or something because it didn't work the first time. So I ended up doing `const newArticle = new Article(ctx.request.body); newArticle.save()`  What you provided works like a charm~  What might be the cons for me doing `newArticle.save()` though?

Comment: P.S. so by doing `create: async(ctx)` is actually overriding and `async create(ctx)` is extending? they look too similar so didn't realize that when I scanned through the documents

Comment: It will not use the query system that manages relations and other stuff.
About defining the `create` function, both are correct and will do the same thing.
Can you set the question as answered, it will help to know this topic id OK ;)
Thank you.